# How to upload a file in File Filed of Django automatically in backend without manual selection in front-end

Tags: python, django, file, upload, backend

My models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Result(models.Model):
    Id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, blank=False)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # Date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    # Comments = models.TextField(max_length=256)
    File = models.FileField(blank=False)
```

My views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from contextmapping.Connection import Connection

from rest_framework.response import Response 
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from django.shortcuts import render

from rest_framework import viewsets,status
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from result.models import Result

class ResultViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Result.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Result
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)


    @action(detail=True,methods=['GET'])
    def resultfill(self,request,pk=None):
        
        response={'message':'its working'}
        return Response(response,status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I have a file named data1.py in a folder, I want to run resultfill function in views.py by url, and want to give a path to this file and that file should be automatically upload to File in models.py . How to achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use default in your file field and give the path of the file. If you have set up all the media and static file URLS in settings then you can just add 'data1.py' as default.

```
class Result(models.Model):
    Id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, blank=False)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # Date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    # Comments = models.TextField(max_length=256)
    File = models.FileField(default='data1.py')
```

This will link your objects to that file imagining that you have 'media/data1.py' as your file location in case you don't upload your own file from frontend or backend.

Comment: But this file can be different each time I run custom method url , in that case how to do that?

Comment: Instead of uploading directly from front-end i have created custom method and passing file name, which i want program to search in specific folder and upload it to file Filed

Comment: If you don't want to upload it from the Frontend and have those file already generated then you have generate those file inside media file have give those file field a path to that file. For example `Result.objects.create(id=12, Name="name", File="date2.py")`  assuming that you have data2.py inside media file. And same for other file data3.py or data.4 just have those file in media folder and give the field a path to that file.